# Why is Rails resetting user selected times when there are unrelated validation errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this code that allows user to click Add Date to show another line to specify a date time. Screenshot shows user entered two dates:

```
<fieldset class="date_fieldset">
  <%= f.label :user_event_date, "Date", class: "info_inline_control info_label" %>
  <%= f.text_field :user_event_date, class: 'datepicker' %>

  <div class="user_event_inline_container margin_left_ten padding_right_gone">
    <%= f.label  :start_time, "Start", class: 'info_inline_control info_label five_margin_right' %>
    <%= f.time_select :start_time, {:ampm => true}, class: (field_class(@user_event, :start_time) + 'info_inline_control') %>
  </div>

  <div class="user_event_inline_container margin_left_ten padding_right_gone">
    <%= f.label  :end_time, "End", class: 'info_inline_control info_label five_margin_right' %>
    <%= f.time_select :end_time, {:ampm => true}, class: (field_class(@user_event, :end_time) + 'info_inline_control') %>
  </div>

  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to "delete", '#', class: 'remove_fields margin_left_ten' %>
</fieldset>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
    });
  });
</script>
```

[image: two dates entered and OK]

But if some other, non-related field elsewhere on the form has a validation error, and the errors are reported at the top of the form, then the two lines for the user specified dates are gone, and clicking the Add Date button makes the user start over to specify the dates again. How can I prevent page refresh to show validation errors wiping out user selected dates?

[image: user selected dates gone]

Here are the new, edit, and create controller action methods:

```
  def new 
    if !signed_in?
      redirect_to signin_path
    else
      @user_event = UserEvent.new
      @user_event.event_dates.build
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @user_event = current_user.user_events.build(params[:user_event])
    if @user_event.save

      flash[:success] = "Event was successfully posted!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render action: :new
    end
  end
```

As always, thanks very much for your answers in advance!

Comment: Can you post the controller action for the form?

Comment: Are you redirecting back to the new or edit actions, and do the attributes in the form map directly to model attributes by their precise names (so that the form is re-filled with them)?

Comment: I think if the save fails I render new again, as seen above in my controller create method. But the user entered information is retained, except for the dates. Perhaps I should rediect to edit page. I'm wondering if this might be happening because the two date entry lines are generated when user clicks Add Date, so they are not "real"?

Comment: I added an edit view (basically a copy of the "new" view for now), and changed the controller to redirect to edit if save does not succeed. Edit action method has no code though, because I can't query database for the user event record as it has not been saved. Should I manually store the specified date/time info somewhere and use it to repopulate?

Comment: BTW, I went back to re-directing to new if save fails due to validation errors, because I'm thinking that's how it should be (though I could be wrong). Just need to figure out how to save those specified dates and re-populate new view ui.

Comment: Just wondering if anyone can help fill in the missing pieces to this puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

This solves it:

```
<div>
  <%= f.fields_for :event_dates do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'event_date_fields', f: builder %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Before, I had an empty div, and Javascript would add an event date each time the Add Date link was clicked. But when the page is re-rendered, either due to validation errors, or else because used is editing the event, the div needs f.fields_for to render what already exists.

Man I'm loving Rails, and the community, because I get pieces of the puzzle, and figure out the rest.